# Regular expression to replace query

Tags: php, mysql, regex

can someone make a regular expression FOR NOTEPAD++ for me to replace this query:

```
mysql_query($query, $db);
```

replace by:

```
$mysqli->query($query)
```

But $query could also have another variable name, for example $query_2, so the output should be

```
$mysqli->query($query2)
```

Thank you!

Comment: you need an regular expression to change your source code? Don't you need a search & replace on your project?

Comment: Yes, I need it to change my source code. And that's indeed what I need!

Comment: I prefer to change them manually!

Comment: what about a wrapper??

Comment: Yes, I want to do that, but my website is very complex with hundreds/thousands of query's in all my scripts, so I would like to create a Regular Expression to replace them.

Comment: @LuisSiquot, I will implement that in a following website update, now I need to change them manually for an upcoming update;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works in Notepad++ 6.3.2. This accommodates any issues with inconsistent space and tab characters potentially being used.

**Search Pattern**

```
mysql_query\(\s*\$([^,\s]+)\s*,\s*\$db\s*\);
```

**Replacement**

```
\$mysqli->query\(\$\1\);
```

(Make sure *Regular Expression* radio button is selected in the *replace* dialogue box).

**test Text**

```
mysql_query($query, $db);
mysql_query($SQL , $db);
mysql_query($query2,    $db);
mysql_query( $SQL_v4, $db );
mysql_query($AnotherSQL,$db);
```

**Output Text**

```
$mysqli->query($query);
$mysqli->query($SQL);
$mysqli->query($query2);
$mysqli->query($SQL_v4);
$mysqli->query($AnotherSQL);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$input = 'mysql_query($asdf, $db);';
$input = preg_replace('/mysql_query\(\$(\w+), \$db\);/','\$mysqli->query(\$$1);',$input);
echo $input;
```

Outputs `$mysqli->query($asdf);`

**EDIT:**

On Notepad++, try this:

1. Find what: `mysql_query\(\$(\w+), *\$db\);`
2. Replace with: `\$mysqli->query\(\$$1\);`

Comment: I try to place the regular expression in the Notepad++ search window, but it replaces everything to $mysqli->query($1);

Comment: Don't forget to check the "Regular expression" checkbox.

Comment: I did, but everything is exactly replaced with \$mysqli->query\(\$$1\);

Comment: It works well for me. What do you mean by "replaces everything"? Is it erasing all your file and replacing it with that?

Comment: No, he searches for the mysql_query, but for example mysql_query($query, $db); is replaced by \$mysqli->query\(\$$1\);

Comment: @Jordy, Racso's pattern is fine, you can test it [here](http://www.functions-online.com/preg_replace.html). Your problem might be in the version of PHP you are running because older versions don't recognize `$n` as backreferences and you might have to use something like `\\1` or something else. check `preg_replace` documentation.

Comment: I've tested on Notepad++ v6.2.2, and the replace works as expected, unless there is not exactly one space between the comma and `, $db` in the string to be matched. The addition of an asterisk following the space in the RE handles zero, one or more spaces.  `mysql_query\(\$(\w+), *\$db\);`

Comment: I've put the asterisk :)